# is there any way to fix ruby gem error?

Tags: ruby, security

Is there a way to fix this I am using a lenovoy50 windows 8.1 OS
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
Your Ruby version is 2.1.5, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.2

Answer (score 0):

Change the version in your Gemfile to match the version of Ruby that you're using. Replace this line:

```
ruby '2.1.2'
```

With this line:

```
ruby '2.1.5'
```

The other line about DL is a warning and can be ignored.